# imagePoints output of projectPoints()

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have a question regarding the imagepoints output of the projectPoints() funtion in open CV. I am getting image points which have negative coordinates and I understand that they are outside the screen area definitely.

However, what should be the maximum range of outputs for the imagePoints for them to be on the screen?

Will it be u= 1280 and v=720 if I am using it for an image that has 1280 pixels width and 720 pixels height?

**Addendum: For a clearer exposition of my problem I add the following details,**

```
camera_distCoeffs: [0.045539, -0.057822, 0.001451, -0.000487, 0.006539, 0.438100, -0.135970, 0.011170]

camera_intrinsic: [606.215365, 0.000000, 632.285550, 0.000000, 679.696865, 373.770687, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]                          

Sample camera coordinate: [16.7819794502, -2.2923261485, 2.9228301598] with orientation quaternions:[Qx,Qy,Qz,Qw] as [0.0075078838, 0.062947858, 0.3573477229, -0.9318174734] 

Sample target coordinate: [-8.2578747838,-2.0245720753, 6.5551989493]
```

I am forming my rotation vector (rvec) by first converting the quaternions to rotation matrix and then calling the Rodrigues() function. I am constructing the translation vector as tvec=-(transpose of rotation matrix)*[column vector of camera cordinates]

Also,  from what I understand the pinhole camera model used in the projectPoints() function has the camera aperture as the origin. So does it mean that the input parameter 'objectPoints' should be (x-x1, y-y1, z-z1) in my case where the camera is not the origin ? for brevity, here  (x1,y1,z1)  is camera coordinate in world frame and (x,y,z) is target object coordinate in world frame.

Comment: Everything depends on your camera matrix, with the cx, cy values of this matrix you can estimate the size of the valid image. Modifying the focus can do a zoom in or zoom out effect, that may help you get more pixels into the image. If all points are weird, it could be that your points lie behind the camera (usually changing the z axis fix this), or that your points are around the origin (centered in the model and not the camera)

Comment: I understand. But does the projectPoints() function output the u,v coordinates in pixel units already scaled by the scaling factor 's'?

Comment: i do not see any scale factor s in [calibrateCamera](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera)...

Comment: at the top of the page in the matrix equation there is a scaling factor 's'. However to make my question clearer, from the project points function I am getting outputs like (5134.34,7001.96) which I assume are the pixel coordinates. But since the image size is 1024x720 p (I am using a still image of the object) do I have to scale the output somehow ? If so, then how do I determine the scaling factor?

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh, yes that one is managed by the function. When you solve the right hand of the equation you end with a 2D point in homogeneous coordinate system. Let's say (x,y,z). To transform it to 2D point in no homogenous form, you do (x/z, y/z, z/z) and remove the last component (x/z, y/z). Then s = 1/z. If you get those values, probably your camera matrix is wrong, you can edit your question with it, and maybe the points used in project points (and extrinsic matrix). This way someone can test and maybe pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Also, not all 3D points will be in the image plane, and may give you bigger or smaller values than your image plane size. If you want to draw an  image with 3D info, just discard this points.

Comment: I have added the details :) I hope it gives a clearer idea of the problem I am having

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to test it, but you can try applying the extrinsics manually to understand where your point is before it is projected :) This means, create your rotation matrix and translation [R|T] and apply it to a point. Then you can see where your point is in space